# Argparse not parsing arguments properly on CentOS 7

Tags: python, centos7, argparse

I am setting up a server on a CentOS 7 machine that will periodically run Python scripts. However, I am having issues with argparse parsing the arguments passed to the script.

Here's the snippet of my argument setup:

```
    main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
     description=__doc__,
     formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    main_parser.add_argument('--loglevel','-l',
                             help='loglevel NONE, NORMAL, VERBOSE, VVERBOSE, DEBUG',
                             default="ERROR")

    main_parser.add_argument("--dbfile", "-d", default="archi_tool.db")
    main_parser.add_argument("--prefix", "-p", default="LSST_")
    main_parser.set_defaults(func=None) # if none then there are  subfunctions
    subparsers = main_parser.add_subparsers(title="subcommands",
                       description='valid subcommands',
                       help='additional help')
    # Subcommand  to ingest csv to sqlite3 db file
    mkdb_parser = subparsers.add_parser('mkdb', description=mkdb.__doc__)
    mkdb_parser.set_defaults(func=mkdb)
    mkdb_parser.add_argument("--force", "-f", help="remove existing db file of the same name", default=False, action='store_true')


    # Subcommand  to ingest csv to sqlite3 db file
    ingest_parser = subparsers.add_parser('ingest', description=ingest.__doc__)
    ingest_parser.set_defaults(func=ingest)
    #ingest_parser.add_argument("sqldbfile")

    list_parser = subparsers.add_parser('list', description=list.__doc__)
    list_parser.set_defaults(func=list)
    list_parser.add_argument(   "--chr", "-c", help='Chromosome Numbers' , default='1')

    # Subcommand  to ingest csv to sqlite3 db file
    era_ingest_parser = subparsers.add_parser('era_ingest', description=era_ingest.__doc__)
    era_ingest_parser.set_defaults(func=era_ingest)

    dbinfo_parser = subparsers.add_parser('dbinfo', description=dbinfo.__doc__)
    dbinfo_parser.set_defaults(func=dbinfo)

    # reasonably detailed list of model summary information
    modelinfo_parser = subparsers.add_parser('modelinfo', description=modelinfo.__doc__)
    modelinfo_parser.set_defaults(func=modelinfo)

    # reasonably detailed list of model summary information
    like_parser = subparsers.add_parser('like', description=like.__doc__)
    like_parser.set_defaults(func=like)
    like_parser.add_argument("pattern", help="SQL pattern for matching")

    archi_interface.parsers(subparsers)
    conventions.parsers(subparsers)

    args = main_parser.parse_args()
```

I try to initiate the following command:

```
python archi_tool.py -l VERBOSE -p LSST mkdb
```

I've also tried the verbose variant:

```
python archi_tool.py --loglevel VERBOSE --prefix LSST mkdb
```

On CentOS 7 it fails as if no arguments had been passed or -h had been called, showing the "usage" printout. I've tried running with system python (2.7.5) and python 2.7.0 installed through pyenv.

The script had been tested on MacOS with python 2.7.10 and python 2.7 and Ubuntu with python 2.7.10. The script runs flawlessly in these environments, but not CentOS. I've even tried copy-pasting the command above into MacOS terminal and CentOS ssh to make sure I'm typing it right, but the outcome is the same.

What is up with CentOS? Does it treat arguments in a different manner?

Comment: Have you looked at `sys.argv`?  Look at what's there on MacOS, and compare that with what you get on CenOS.  OS differences are more likely to affect that input, rather than the operation of `argparse` itself (which is pure Python).

Comment: @hpaulj I've added a print(sys.argv) to the code on both machines. In MacOS it is ['archi_tool.py', '-l', 'VERBOSE', '-p', 'LSST', 'mkdb'] and on CentOS it is ['archi_tool.py', '-l', 'VERBOSE', '-p', 'LSST', 'mkdb']. Identical. However, I've noticed that further down the code (in a section I haven't posted) there's a help printer if not args.func. I'll investigate this issue.

Comment: @hpaulj I've taken a closer look, and argparse apparently is not picking up the trailing subparser (i.e. "mkdb") - I've added print(args.func), and it always returns none. I've tied putting it in quotes, but it does not help. Same exact code picks it up successfully on MacOS and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Update: it turned out, python 2.7.10 installed through pyenv had done the trick, and args.func is now properly assigned through func=mkdb in the subparser.